# Where is the actual executable of LiveUSB-Creator located on Fedora?

Tags: fedora, python, application

I don't really know how to phrase this question any better, so let's go with an example:

I installed `liveusb-creator` on my Fedora a while ago and I wonder where the files it executes are located.
I know about `which` and `whereis`:

`which liveusb-creator
/usr/sbin/liveusb-creator`

`liveusb-creator` itself is some piece of Python code which contains, along with some method `parse_args()` which simply does what its name says, this:

```
    import sys
    import os        
    from liveusb import _

    def parse_args():
         #
         # some code that handles parsing command line arguments...
         #

    def main():
        opts, args = parse_args()
        if opts.console:
            from liveusb import LiveUSBCreator
            try:
                live = LiveUSBCreator(opts)
                live.detect_removable_drives()
                live.verify_filesystem()
                live.extract_iso()
                live.update_configs()
                live.install_bootloader()
            except Exception, e:
                print str(e)
            x = raw_input("\nDone!  Press any key to exit")
        else:
            ## Start our graphical interface
            from liveusb.gui import LiveUSBApp
            try:
                LiveUSBApp(opts, sys.argv)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                pass

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        if sys.platform != 'win32':
            if os.getuid() != 0:
                print >> sys.stderr, _("You must run this application as root")
                sys.exit(1)
        main()
```

It occurred to me that the Python code itself isn't the program that you see when you run the LiveUSB-application. I don't understand Python so this is kind of cryptic for me: 
Where is the actual file that gets executed?

It also seems to do some import magic in

`from liveusb import LiveUSBCreator`

How does it know what `liveusb` and `LiveUSBCreator` are?

Comment: Those methods inside the `try` block are the main part of the script. Google them one by one to see what they do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line of the script probably should start with `#!`, followed by the name of the python interpreter. (Like `/usr/bin/env python`.) You can start it manually in a terminal, and add a `-v`:

```
/usr/bin/env python -v
```

it will overwhelm you with 100 lines of information because of the `-v`. To see the location of the `liveusb` python module, type

```
import liveusb
```

(or `from liveusb import _`), press enter, and you should get the information you are looking for.

Use Control+D to exit.